# Can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item

Tags: rust

In this code everything works except `task_id`. I want this script to count requests in `task_id`:

```
use std::thread;
use std::thread::sleep_ms;
use std::sync::mpsc;
#[macro_use] extern crate nickel;
use nickel::Nickel;

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    let mut task_id: i64 = 0;

    server.utilize(router! {
        get "**" => |_req, _res| {
            task_id += 1;
            run_heavy_task(task_id);
            "Yo!"
        }
    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
}

fn run_heavy_task(task_id: i64) {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        println!("heavy task {} started!", task_id);
        sleep_ms(3000);
        println!("heavy task {} completed", task_id);
        let result = tx.send(());
    });


    //rx.recv();
    //println!("Task {} completed", task_id);
}
```

error:

> can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item; use the || { ... }
>   closure form instead main.rs:13             task_id += 1;

Please help me solve this issue - how can I pass task_id into closure?

Comment: `router!` is sugar that expands to a function (https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs/blob/master/src/macros.rs). A function cannot close over variables, nor will this approach work. Bear in mind how it may be multi-threaded; at the very least you will need to use some form of mutex to get it to work.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan as I said, this code, without task_id, works fine: https://gist.github.com/jamm/d067307206c8420c7388, "nor will this approach work" is a wrong statement. "at the very least you will need to use some form of mutex to get it to work" - I don't change task_id inside spawned functions, so I don't need mutex.

Comment: @OZ_: you misunderstood I think, the point of Chris is that the function created by `router!` changes `task_id`, and this function might be called from multiple threads (as far as the Rust compiler knows), so even if it could close over variables (which it cannot) you would need some form of synchronization.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Chris Morgan's answer, this is a self-contained example with the same error:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = 0;
    fn router() {
        a += 1;
    }
    router();
    println!("{}", a)
}
```

The problem is that `fn` items are *not allowed to capture their environment*, period. Capturing environment is non-trivial, and there are multiple ways to get variables into a closure. Closures are actually structs with the appropriate member variables for each captured variable.

Review Chris Morgan's statement:

> Bear in mind how it **may** be multi-threaded; at the very least you will need to use some form of mutex to get it to work.

(Emphasis mine). You are creating a function, but you *don't get to control how or when it is called*. For all you know, Nickel may choose to call it from multiple threads - that's up to the library. As it is, **you** do not ever call the code `task_id += 1`!

I'm no expert on Nickel, but it appears that having dynamic routing is not possible with the code you've posted. However, it should be possible for you to avoid using the macro and [construct a handler yourself](https://github.com/nickel-org/nickel.rs/blob/8c07dd712883029df4c2fb813bc2deea668daaa9/src/nickel.rs#L60-L62), you "just" need to implement [`Middleware`](http://docs.nickel.rs/nickel/trait.Middleware.html). That handler may be able to contain state, like your `task_id`.